# How to get the column number in slick grid

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

Is there a way to get the column numbers for the columns that got changed after column reorder for jquery slickgrid ?

I want to get the column number whose position got changed on onColumnsReordered event

Answer (score 0):

You can use .getColumns() to get the new reordered column list.  If you asking about just getting the deltas, there's no built-in way to do that.